# SQLalchemy setting constraints on relationships in many-to-many

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

Suppose I have a set of users and each user has access to a collection of tools. The same tool might have many users with access so this is a many-to-many relationship:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    tools = db.relationship("Tool", secondary=user_tool_assoc_table,
                            back_populates='users')

class Tool(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tool'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=False)

user_tool_assoc_table = db.Table('user_tool', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('user', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('tool', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tool.id')))
```

Observe that user names are unique, but tool names are not. So `User.name:Mike1` and `User.name:Mike2` might have access to `Tool.name:Hammer`, and, separately, `User.name:John1` and `User.name:John2` might have access to `Tool.name:Hammer` by the same name but each with different `Tool.ids`.

**I want to make a constraint that within the `User.tools` collection there can never be a tool with the same name as another**, i.e.

- A user cannot create a new `Tool` as part of his collection if one with that name already exists. `Mike1` cannot create a new tool called `Hammer` that forms part of his `tools` collection.
- A `Tool` that exists in the database cannot be appended to the `tools` collection of a user if one with the same name already exists in the set, i.e. John1's `Hammer` cannot be shared with Mike1 since Mike1 already has his own `Hammer`.
- `James`, however, can create a new `Hammer` since he does not already have a hammer. There will then be 3 tools in the database called `Hammer` each with a distinct set of `Users`.
- Note in my specific case a `Tool` will only exist if it has at least one `User`, but I also don't know how to ensure this natively in my database.

Is this possible natively with SQLalchemy to automatically configure my database to maintain integrity? I don't want to write my own validator rules since I will likely miss something and end up with a database which breaks my rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is how to express the predicate "A user identified by ID has only one tool with the name NAME". This would of course be easy to express with a simple table such as:

```
db.Table('user_toolname',
         db.Column('user', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
         db.Column('toolname', db.String, primary_key=True))
```

It is also very clear that this alone is not nearly enough to uphold integrity, as there is no connection between the fact about user's toolnames and the actual tools. Your database could state that a user both has a hammer and doesn't have a hammer.

It would be nice to enforce this in your `user_tool_assoc_table` or something equivalent, but since `Tool.name` is not a part of the primary key of `Tool`, you cannot reference it. On the other hand since you do want to allow multiple tools with the same name to co-exist, the subset *{ id, name }* is in fact the proper key for `Tool`:

```
class Tool(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tool'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
```

The `id` now acts as a "discriminator" of sorts between the tools having the same name. Note that `id` need not be globally unique in this model, but locally to `name`. It's handy to have it auto increment still, but the default setting of [`autoincrement='auto'`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement) only treats a single-column integer primary key as having auto incrementing behavior by default, so it must be explicitly set.

It is now possible to define `user_tool_assoc_table` in terms of `tool_name` as well, with the additional constraint that a user can only have a single tool with a given name:

```
user_tool_assoc_table = db.Table(
    'user_tool',
    db.Column('user', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('tool', db.Integer),
    db.Column('name', db.String),
    db.ForeignKeyConstraint(['tool', 'name'],
                            ['tool.id', 'tool.name']),
    db.UniqueConstraint('user', 'name'))
```

With this model and the following setup:

```
john = User(name='John')
mark = User(name='Mark')
db.session.add_all([john, mark])
hammer1 = Tool(name='Hammer')
hammer2 = Tool(name='Hammer')
db.session.add_all([hammer1, hammer2])
db.session.commit()
```

This will succeed:

```
john.tools.append(hammer1)
hammer2.users.append(mark)
db.session.commit()
```

And this will fail after the above, since it violates the unique constraint:

```
john.tools.append(hammer2)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Just noticed your last constraint that a tool should not exist without an accompanying user or users.

Comment: Marvellous work on the initial part, the last constraint was a bit of a luxury, still I am keen to know the answer if possible. I'll give this a try and come back

Comment: I realized that I overcomplicated this quite a bit (and introduced an anomaly in the process): in fact the proper key for your original `Tool` model is *(id, name)*, and so the mapping over a join is unnecessary. The association table stays mostly the same. I'll update (rewrite) this a bit later.

Comment: Thanks, I think I know what you are hinting at but it will be good to see the final version to make sure. This stuff makes sense after a bit of experience I think, which I am, unfortunately, lacking in this area.

Comment: The only change I see this introduces is an extension to the primary key, and adding specific constraint on the association table - which is nice. Hopefully I can implement this as is: but User is actually a polymorphic subclass of another BaseClass which has only one primary key on id itself, so this will be another problem to solve.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to model the domain by allowing tool names to be non-unique, then there is no easy way to accomplish this.

You can try adding a validator to the User model which will check the `User.tools` list during every append and make sure that it obeys a certain condition

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates
class User(db.Model):
  __tablename__ = 'user'
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
  tools = db.relationship("Tool", secondary=user_tool_assoc_table,
                        back_populates='users')

  @validates('tools')
  def validate_tool(self, key, tool):
    assert tool.name not in [t.name for t in self.tools]
    return tool

  def __repr__(self):
    return self.name
```

The above approach will make sure that if you add a new tool which has the same name as an existing tools in `user.tools` list it will throw an exception. But the problem is that you can still directly assign a new list with duplicate tools directly like this

`mike.tools = [hammer1, hammer2, knife1]`

This will work because `validates` works only during append operation. Not during assignment. If we want a solution that works even during assignment, then we will have to figure out a solution where `user_id` and `tool_name` will be in the same table.

We can do this by making the secondary association table have 3 columns `user_id`, `tool_id` and `tool_name`. We can then make `tool_id` and `tool_name` to behave as a `Composite Foreign Key` together (Refer https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#defining-foreign-keys)

By this approach, the association table will have a standard foreign key to `user_id` and then a composite foreign key constraint which combines `tool_id` and `tool_name`. Now that both keys are there in the association table, we can then proceed to define an `UniqueConstraint` on the table which will make sure that `user_id` and `tool_name` will have to be an unique combination

Here is the code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates
from sqlalchemy.schema import ForeignKeyConstraint, UniqueConstraint

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

user_tool_assoc_table = db.Table('user_tool', db.Model.metadata,
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('tool_id', db.Integer),
    db.Column('tool_name', db.Integer),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['tool_id', 'tool_name'], ['tool.id', 'tool.name']),
    UniqueConstraint('user_id', 'tool_name', name='unique_user_toolname')
)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    tools = db.relationship("Tool", secondary=user_tool_assoc_table,
                            back_populates='users')


    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name


class Tool(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tool'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=False)
    users = db.relationship("User", secondary=user_tool_assoc_table,
                            back_populates='tools')

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{0} - ID: {1}".format(self.name, self.id)

db.create_all()

mike=User(name="Mike")
pete=User(name="Pete")
bob=User(name="Bob")

db.session.add_all([mike, pete, bob])
db.session.commit()

hammer1 = Tool(name="hammer")
hammer2 = Tool(name="hammer")

knife1 = Tool(name="knife")
knife2 = Tool(name="knife")

db.session.add_all([hammer1, hammer2, knife1, knife2])
db.session.commit()
```

Now let's try playing around

```
In [2]: users = db.session.query(User).all()

In [3]: tools = db.session.query(Tool).all()

In [4]: users
Out[4]: [Mike, Pete, Bob]

In [5]: tools
Out[5]: [hammer - ID: 1, hammer - ID: 2, knife - ID: 3, knife - ID: 4]

In [6]: users[0].tools = [tools[0], tools[2]]

In [7]: db.session.commit()

In [9]: users[0].tools.append(tools[1])

In [10]: db.session.commit()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IntegrityError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-a8e4ec8c4c52> in <module>()
----> 1 db.session.commit()

/home/surya/Envs/inkmonk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.pyc in do(self, *args, **kwargs)
    151 def instrument(name):
    152     def do(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 153         return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
    154     return do
```

So appending a tool of the same name throws exception.

Now let's try assigning a list with duplicate tool names

```
In [14]: tools
Out[14]: [hammer - ID: 1, hammer - ID: 2, knife - ID: 3, knife - ID: 4]

In [15]: users[0].tools = [tools[0], tools[1]]

In [16]: db.session.commit()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IntegrityError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-a8e4ec8c4c52> in <module>()
----> 1 db.session.commit()

/home/surya/Envs/inkmonk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.pyc in do(self, *args, **kwargs)
    151 def instrument(name):
    152     def do(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 153         return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
    154     return do
```

This throws an exception as well. So we have made sure at db level that your requirement is solved.

But in my opinion, taking such a convoluted approach usually indicates that we are needlessly complicating the design. If you are ok with changing the table design, please consider the following suggestion for a simpler approach.

In my opinion, it is better to have a set of unique tools and a set of unique users and then model a M2M relationship between them. Any property which is specific to Mike's hammer, but not present in James' hammer should be a property of that association between them.

If you take that approach, you have a set of users like this

> Mike, James, John, George

and a set of tools like this

> Hammer, Screwdriver, Wedge, Scissors, Knife

And you can still model a many to many relation between them. In this scenario, the only change you have to do is to set `unique=True` on the `Tool.name` column, so that there is only one hammer globally which can have that name.

If you need Mike's hammer to have some unique properties distinct from James's Hammer, then you can just add some extra columns in the association table. To access user.tools and tool.users, you can use an association_proxy.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.associationproxy import association_proxy

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    associated_tools = db.relationship("UserToolAssociation")

    tools = association_proxy("associated_tools", "tool")

class Tool(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'tool'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, unique=True)
    associated_users = db.relationship("UserToolAssociation")

    users = association_proxy("associated_users", "user")



class UserToolAssociation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user_tool_association'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    tool_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tool.id'))
    property1_specific_to_this_user_tool = db.Column(db.String(20))
    property2_specific_to_this_user_tool = db.Column(db.String(20))

    user = db.relationship("User")
    tool = db.relationship("Tool")
```

The above approach is better because of the proper separation of concerns. In future when you need to do something that will affect all hammers, you can just modify the hammer instance in the Tools table. If you keep all hammers as separate  instances without any link between them, it will become cumbersome to do any modification on them as a whole in the future.

Comment: Shouldn't the composite foreign key reference a key? In its current form in that part of the question the *(id, name)* of `Tool` is not a key, though. Excellent point on moving the unique-to-an-association attributes to the association table.

Comment: I agree that it is convoluted, but the constraint is a rather specific situation which altering would create other more major problems (not obvious from my User-Tool analogy) I appreciate the answer very much.

Comment: @IljaEverilä I agree that a composite foreign key should be ideally modelled as a Foreign Key Constraint mapping to 2 independent primary keys on the foreign table. And in this case Tool.name is not a primary key column, but is still being used as a part of the foreign key constraint. I wondered about this and hence tried out various kinds of operations to see if the solution worked as expected. It seems to work ( As shown in the console output in the above answer). Hence posted it. 
But yeah, I agree that there might be some side effect to this method. I am not sure what it is though.